# How to fix gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, gradlew, minecraft-forge

I want to do a 1.8.9 minecraft mod but when i do `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse` it shows me an error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '19.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I tried the command `gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse` and exepted it to work .

Comment: Looks like your Gradle is too old to understand your installed Java version. Upgrade Gradle or downgrade Java.

Comment: maybe try with Java 8... (Minecraft 1.8.9 is not the newest version)